# Array handling in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have the following two objects in my mongo db.

```
{

    "schema":
    {
        "tag1": [
        {
            "path": "/homeAddress",
                "sourceId": "1234"
        }],


            "something1": [
            {
                "path": "/Profile/properties/id",

            }],
            "iwantthis": [
            {
                "namespace": ["namespace1"]
            },
            {
                "namespace": ["namespace2"]
            }],

    }
}

{

    "schema":
    {
        "tag1": [
        {
            "path": "/homeAddress",
                "sourceId": "1234"
        }],


            "something1": [
            {
                "path": "/Profile/properties/id",

            }],
            "iwantthis": [
            {
                "namespace": ["namespace3"]
            },
            {
                "namespace": ["namespace4"]
            }],

    }
}
```

I am given two namespaces:

1. namespace1
2. namespace2

I have to form a query to fetch all the objects that have the two namespaces mentioned above.

MongoDB reference guide is not very helpful here.
Any thoughts please?

Comment: What are the ` two namespaces mentioned above`?

Comment: I am given two namespaces,  namespace2. They are two string values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to find inside the array with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```
db.collection.find({
  "schema.iwantthis": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "namespace": { "$in": ["namespace1", "namespace2"] }
    }
  }
})
```